# How to get past the X-MSDAVEXT_Error=917656 issue when obtaining sharepoint online cookies?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, security-token-service

I'm getting an issue basically described perfectly here: https://www.undocumented-features.com/2019/12/02/resolved-sharepoint-online-web-site-does-not-support-sharepoint-online-credentials/

To authenticate, I am using the binary security token form of authentication. When I attempt to obtain the SPOIDCRL cookie from SharePoint I get spit back:

```
"Authorization: BPOSIDCRL t=Ew.....jiwC&p=[\r][\n]"
 "Host: mytenant.sharepoint.com[\r][\n]"
 "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
 "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.6 (Java/1.8.0_171)[\r][\n]"
 "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
 "[\r][\n]"
 "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
 "Cache-Control: private[\r][\n]"
 "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
 "P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"[\r][\n]"
 "X-SharePointHealthScore: 1[\r][\n]"
 "X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319[\r][\n]"
 "SPRequestGuid: 78...d09[\r][\n]"
 "request-id: 783...09[\r][\n]"
 "MS-CV: n8Q...Q.0[\r][\n]"
 "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000[\r][\n]"
 "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
 "X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.[\r][\n]"
 "SPRequestDuration: 18[\r][\n]"
 "SPIisLatency: 1[\r][\n]"
 "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
 "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.21221[\r][\n]"
 "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
 "X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly[\r][\n]"
 "X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 8B389A9AB7E14D9C8D5EBE533C51FB1D Ref B: BLUEDGE1221 Ref C: 2021-05-03T08:49:05Z[\r][\n]"
 "Date: Mon, 03 May 2021 08:49:04 GMT[\r][\n]"
 "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
 "[\r][\n]"
```

The link above says to go in and check some settings to allow apps that use older methods of authentication. I cannot change that setting.

Is there some other, newer way to obtain SPOICRL cookies other than the old binary security token method?

I cannot use App-Only auth either because it pretty much forces you to make the appClientID a full admin to be able to really use it to do anything with the Rest API.

So I really need to be able to use service account authentication.

Comment: Having the exact same issue. Did you ever get a resolution Nicholas DiPiazza?